# Poco / zlib: error LNK2019 unresolved external "_gzopen"

Tags: poco, zlib, poco-libraries

I am trying to use zlib functions while working with poco c++ library. Linking to the zlib library directly does not work, because poco links to it also and I get several duplicates while linking. So I removed zlib.lib from my libraries list and used the poco version only.

Because zlib.h is part of poco, compiling works perfectly, but linking now results in the following error

```
error LNK2019 unresolved external "_gzopen"
```

So I can switch between `duplicate` and `unresolved`. Who can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows, defining [ZLIB_DLL](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/zconf.h#L309) should force export of native zlib interface. Optionally, Poco [InflatingStream](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/InflatingStream.h#L57) and [DeflatingStream](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/DeflatingStream.h#L57) wrap zlib functionality. A word of warning: these are std streams derivatives and there may be a performance penalty.

Comment: When should I use ZLIB_DLL? While compiling Poco or compiling my project? And...I do not want to have a zlib.dll, I want my static Poco libs to expose the zlib functions...

Comment: OK, I looked into it a bit deeper - [gzlib.c](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/gzlib.c) (where [gzopen](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/gzlib.c#L262) definition is) is distributed with POCO but actually not included in Foundation project, that's why you are seeing the link error. In order to avoid changes to POCO VS project, it is best to include gzlib.c from POCO distribution into your application and it should resolve; I tried including gzlib.c and calling gzopen from a Foundation sample application and it links fine.